# How to save changed variables from class php

Tags: php, class, variables, save

Hi I want to know what am I doing wrong, and how can I save class variables into file.

```
class x{
 public $xy=0;
 function saveConfig($src){
    $classArray = get_class_vars(get_class($this));
    $line='';
    foreach ($classArray as $k => $v) {
        if(is_array($v)){
            $line.=$k.'='.implode('|',$v)."\r\n";
        }else if(isset($v)) $line.=$k.'='.$v."\r\n";
    }
    file_put_contents($src,$line);
    echo $line;//test
    return true;
 }
}
```

This is test class. When running:

```
$test=new x;
$test->xy=5;
$test->saveConfig('testSrc.txt');
```

I'll get output "xy=0", but I want it to save/echo changed variable, that's mean "xy=5".

What is wrong with this code, why and how can I correct it ?

Comment: You have an answer, but also: why not use `json_encode()` or even `var_export()` so that the definitions in the file are easily used?

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this functions in other projects, right now it's a part of bigger code, where everything is set, only this part left...(original class is much bigger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `get_class_vars(get_class($this))` to `get_object_vars($this)`.
`get_class_vars` returns the default properties of a class. `get_object_vars` returns the current properties of an object (an instance of a class).